# Check for special characters in every JSON field

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON obj like below -

```
let json = 
{
    "mobileNumber": "9876543210",
    "firstName": "firstName",
    "environment": "environment",
    "MORE_DATA": {
        "sessionId": "sessionId",
        "check": "before",
        "mobileTrue": "some<>!"
    }
}
```

I want to check if all the JSON fields do not have special characters in them.

I can individually access each field and test it like this

```
let format = /[ <>\/:+=?'"; ]/;
format.test(json.mobileNumber); //gives false
format.test(json.MORE_DATA.mobileTrue); //gives true
```

How do I test this in a more effective manner which tests all the fields and returns true or false ?

Comment: That's a JavaScript object. There's no JSON anywhere in your question.

Comment: People *do* have names which include some of the characters you want to forbid in names. If your goal is to defend against XSS or SQL injection then trying to filter out special characters is the wrong approach.

Comment: you can use lodash fucntion _.forOwn(object, (k,v)=>{..//Implementation goes here}) and check for each field the format and